# (matlab) Hold on doesn't work for large data sets

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot nine sets of x,y data points on the same graph, blocked off into three different colors. With my particular data,

```
hold on
```

works but only for the first four sets, after which new sets will erase the old ones. Each set has approximately 1500 points. If I plot 150 points with each set, the problem occurs after seven sets.

Thanks

Comment: I can reproduce your error. Have you tried to increase the Java Heap Memory? To adjust the Java heap size:
On the Home tab, in the Environment section, click Preferences. Select MATLAB > General > Java Heap Memory.
Select a Java heap size value using the slider or spin box. ...
Click OK.
Restart MATLAB.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Mac, with MATLAB 2016a. Can you post a [mcve] and the MATLAB/OS version you're using?

Comment: @C.Colden, that worked! Thank you. I am using using 2012B with windows 10.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer below than to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the Java Heap Memory size:

On the Home tab, in the Environment section, click Preferences.
Select MATLAB > General > Java Heap Memory.
Select a Java heap size value using the slider or spin box. ... Click OK.
 Restart MATLAB.